# seaborn ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (XX,1) into shape (XX,)

Tags: python, seaborn, knn

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

wine = load_wine()
wine_data = wine.data
wine_target = wine.target

df = pd.DataFrame(data=wine_data, columns = [wine.feature_names])
df['target']=wine.target
print(df)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(wine_data, wine_target, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
kn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 7)
kn.fit(train_data, train_target)

print("\n\nTrain Eval : ", kn.score(train_data, train_target))
print("Test Eval : ", kn.score(test_data, test_target),'\n\n')

train_view = pd.DataFrame(data=train_data, columns = [wine.feature_names])
train_view['target']=train_target
print(train_view)

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style()
sns.pairplot(train_view, hue = 'target')
```

In colab(google site), I have an error about displaying pairplot about my dataframe.
but I don't understand this error.

```
[Error : ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (124,1) into shape (124,)][1]

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/_core.py in categorical_order(vector, order)
   1478             try:
-> 1479                 order = vector.cat.categories
   1480             except (TypeError, AttributeError):

11 frames
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in construct_1d_object_array_from_listlike(values)
   1988     # making a 1D array that contains list-likes is a bit tricky:
   1989     result = np.empty(len(values), dtype="object")
-> 1990     result[:] = values
   1991     return result
   1992 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (124,1) into shape (124,)
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Your error is reproducible on my system (and the error message is indeed quite cryptic).  The problem seems to be `pairplot` not ignoring the `nan`  values.  You could drop the `NaN`s: `sns.pairplot(train_view.drop_na, hue='target')`.  There is also a second problem, in how the names of the columns are set. This should be without putting the list of names in a new list, so `train_view = pd.DataFrame(data=train_data, columns=wine.feature_names)` instead of `train_view = pd.DataFrame(data=train_data, columns=[wine.feature_names])`.

Comment: Could there be a problem that in 'train_view' the data type is: MultiIndex?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are doing `columns = [wine.feature_names]`. Just put `columns=wine.feature_names`.

Comment: thank you sir.. I appriciate your answer!